# I want to ensure that my serialevents will not affected by another class

Tags: java, multithreading, event-handling, serial-port

I am writing code that communicates on serially with several machines. Each machine interacts with an instance of a communicator class and that class has a serial port event listener.

When the machine recieves enough data it peforms a test that is quadratic. (cant be helped as the test itself is quadratic) and the input can be large. As a result I am afraid that some of the serial events wont be registered if the code is doing the calculation.

As a solution I considered creating a  Thread that runs the calculation and setting it to sleep during its loop for a time determined by the number of machines connected. However I  then thought that maybe it would be a better idea if I could put that Thread asleep from the serialevent method? is this possible or will the thread not run until the method that is running finishes?

Now in the code below I have included the Thread.sleep within the Calculations method as this is what I was going to do if the serialevent cant interupt the thread

```
private class CalculationThread implements Runnable{
@Override
  public void run() 
    {
          calculateResult();
    }
}}

private void calculateResult() {
    ArrayList<Double> theoretical_vals;
    ArrayList<ArrayList<Double>> theoretical_curves = new ArrayList();
    double current_maxdiff, maxdiff;
    double ao = measurements.get(0).getMeasurement();
    theoretical_vals = RadioCalculations.theoreticalVals(measurements, hf, ao);
    theoretical_curves.add(theoretical_vals);
    int index = 1;
    for (MeasurePoint m : measurements) {
        theoretical_vals = RadioCalculations.calibratecontrolValues(measurements, index, hf);
        try {
            Thread.sleep(20*(parent.getNumberOfTests()-1));} 
        catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Test.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        theoretical_curves.add(theoretical_vals);
        index++;
    }
    index = 1;
    maxdiff = 0;
    for (ArrayList a : theoretical_curves) {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(20*(parent.getNumberOfTests()-1));
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Test.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        current_maxdiff = compareValues(a, measurements);
        if (current_maxdiff > maxdiff) {
            if (current_maxdiff > pass_limit) {
                passed = false;
                failed_measurementpoint = index;
                break;
            }
            maxdiff = current_maxdiff;
            index++;
        }

    }
    passed = true;
    max_dev = maxdiff;
    logResults();
}




public void serialEvent(SerialPortEvent spe) {
    try {
        Thread.sleep(10);
    } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Test.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
   pauseListen(false);     
   if (spe.getEventType()== SerialPortEvent.DATA_AVAILABLE){   

         try {
    while (inputStream.available() > 0) {
                   numBytes =  inputStream.read(readBuffer);}} 
        catch (IOException e) {e.printStackTrace();}
        input_line= new String(readBuffer,0,numBytes);
        input_line = input_line.replaceAll("[\n\r]","*");
        buffer.append(input_line);
        if (input_line.contains("*")){   
        input_line= buffer.toString();
        input_line = input_line.replaceAll("[*]","");
        buffer.setLength(0);
        pauseListen(true);
        update(input_line);}}
}
}
```

Comment: This question is confusing to me. It may be a good idea to have two threads (one for IO and one for calculations) but I don't understand why you're using the sleep function and I don't understand why you're worried about missing data while in a calculation. Even if the calculation takes years, the data will still be waiting for you when you finish. Or do SerialPortEvents overwrite each other?

Answer (score 0):

You could use a [`BlockingQueue`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/BlockingQueue.html) (since Java 5) for put the new calculations in this queue while there is one calculation in *process*.

First, you need a *wrapper* class for you received data of the serial port:

```
class CalculationWrapper {

    // fields
    // getters setters

    public void calculateResult() {
        // operations
    }
}
```

The method `calculateResult` for do the calculations can be in this class or in the next class:

```
class Calculator implements Runnable {
    private final BlockingQueue<CalculationWrapper> queue;

    Calculator(BlockingQueue<CalculationWrapper> q) {
        queue = q;
    }

    public void run() {
        try {
            while (true) {
                CalculationWrapper wrapper = queue.take();
                wrapper.calculateResult();
            }
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            // log error
        }
    }
}
```

The method `take` wait until there is more new calculations in the queue.
The class for the listener of events of serial port (and for put the new calculations) could be:

```
class Receiver implements Runnable, SerialPortEventListener {

    private final BlockingQueue<CalculationWrapper> queue;

    Receiver(BlockingQueue q) {
        queue = q;
    }

    public void run() {
        try {
            while (true) {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            }
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            // log
        }
    }

    public void serialEvent(SerialPortEvent evt) {
        switch (evt.getEventType()) {
            case SerialPortEvent.DATA_AVAILABLE:
                try {
                    // read
                    CalculationWrapper wrapper = new CalculationWrapper();
                    // set data on wrapper
                    queue.put(wrapper);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

And the *setup* class o main class:

```
class Setup {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        // get port
        // register listener

        BlockingQueue q = new ArrayBlockingQueue(10);
        Receiver p = new Receiver(q);
        Calculator c1 = new Calculator(q);
        new Thread(p).start();
        new Thread(c1).start();
    }
}
```

This in one way. See more:

- [Lesson: Concurrency (The Java Tutorials > Essential Classes)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/)
- [SerialPort example « javax.comm « Java by API](http://www.java2s.com/Code/JavaAPI/javax.comm/SerialPortaddEventListenerSerialPortEventListenerarg0.htm)
- [The Java Communications API: A Working Example - By Rick Proctor](http://edn.embarcadero.com/article/31915)